# Using WHERE in SQL

Tags: sql, t-sql, left-join

I do not understand the difference between two coding given below. First one uses `WHERE` in LEFT JOIN. The second code one uses `AND`. I do not understand what is the output I will get from each codings?

```
SELECT c.FirstName, c.LastName, oh.SalesOrderNumber
FROM SalesLT.Customer AS c
LEFT OUTER JOIN SalesLT.SalesOrderHeader AS oh
ON c.CustomerID = oh.CustomerID 
WHERE oh.SalesOrderNumber IS NULL 
ORDER BY c.CustomerID;


SELECT c.FirstName, c.LastName, oh.SalesOrderNumber
FROM SalesLT.Customer AS c
LEFT OUTER JOIN SalesLT.SalesOrderHeader AS oh
ON c.CustomerID = oh.CustomerID  
AND oh.SalesOrderNumber IS NULL 
ORDER BY c.CustomerID;
```

Comment: the two query are the same  ..

Comment: why dont you run them?

Comment: Take a peek at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/44917/explicit-vs-implicit-sql-joins

Comment: I thought so too that both will give same results, but unfortunately, they do not. They give different results, First one gives me 815 rows and second gives me 847 rows.

Comment: @JohnCappelletti Thank you for the link. I have already looked at it.

Comment: @MyurathanKajendran `oh.SalesOrderNumber IS NULL` on the first query actually turned into an inner join, meaning only return customers where `oh.SalesOrderNumber IS NULL`. The 2nd query however returns all customers in `SalesLT.Customer`

Comment: @scaisEdge The queries are actually not the same

Comment: @Stephen   thanks   you are right ..

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In short, the first query applies a filter to the joined tables *after* they are joined, whereas the second query applies it to SalesOrderHeader *before* it is joined to Customer. The distinction is important.

Suppose your Customer table has certain CustomerID's that do not exist in your SalesOrderHeader table. For example, consider the following two tables

```
Customer Table:
+ --------- + -------- + ---------- +
| Firstname | Lastname | CustomerID |
+ --------- + -------- + ---------- +
| Bob       | Dylan    | 1          | 
| Donald    | Trump    | 2          |
| Me Myself | and I    | 14         |
| Guy       | Gisbon   | 86         |
| Megan     | Meganson | 87         |
+ --------- + -------- + ---------- +


SalesOrderHeader Table:
+ ---------------- + ----------- +
| SalesOrderNumber |  CustomerID |
+ ---------------- + ----------- +
| 1681351          | 1           | 
| 1354894          | 86          |
| 1354900          | 13          |
| 1351666          | 86          |
+ ---------------- + ----------- +
```

When you perform the left outer join

```
SELECT c.FirstName, c.LastName, oh.SalesOrderNumber
FROM SalesLT.Customer AS c
LEFT OUTER JOIN SalesLT.SalesOrderHeader AS oh
    ON c.CustomerID = oh.CustomerID
```

you will see all the records from the Customer table (because it is the *left* table), but any unmatched records from the SalesOrderHeader table will appear as nulls. So in our example, you would get

```
Resulting Joined Table
+ --------- + -------- + ---------------- +
| Firstname | Lastname | SalesOrderNumber |
+ --------- + -------- + ---------------- +
| Bob       | Dylan    | 1681351          | 
| Donald    | Trump    | null             |
| Guy       | Gisbon   | 1354894          |
| Guy       | Gisbon   | 1351666          |
| Megan     | Meganson | null             |
+ --------- + -------- + ---------------- +
```

Now if you apply the where clause

```
WHERE oh.SalesOrderNumber IS NULL
```

you are selecting a subset of the result table where the SalesOrderNumber is null. Here, you would get

```
Filter in where clause
+ --------- + -------- + ---------------- +
| Firstname | Lastname | SalesOrderNumber |
+ --------- + -------- + ---------------- +
| Donald    | Trump    | null             |
| Megan     | Meganson | null             |
+ --------- + -------- + ---------------- +
```

Now let's look at the 2nd query, where the null filter is included in the join condition. SQL will look for null SalesOrderNumbers from the SalesOrderHeader table. In our example, we don't have any null records, so you are essentially joining your Customer Table to an empty SalesOrderHeader table. The result would look like

```
Filter in join condition
+ --------- + -------- + ---------------- +
| Firstname | Lastname | SalesOrderNumber |
+ --------- + -------- + ---------------- +
| Bob       | Dylan    | null             | 
| Donald    | Trump    | null             |
| Guy       | Gisbon   | null             |
| Megan     | Meganson | null             |
+ --------- + -------- + ---------------- +
```

This distinction is only important for outer joins. If you're using an inner join, putting the filter in the join condition or in the where clause results in the same thing.

Comment: Thank you so much for the detailed answer. You are a star.